# geting values from arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have the following from my code:

```
stdClass Object ( [orders] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [shipping_address] => stdClass Object ( [first_name] => John [last_name] => Doe [company] => [address_1] => 3927 Walnut Grove [address_2] => [city] => Rosemead [state] => CA [postcode] => 90001 [country] => US ) ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [shipping_address] => stdClass Object ( [first_name] => chris [last_name] => koh [company] => [address_1] => 745 bow [address_2] => [city] => diamond [state] => CA [postcode] => 90015[country] => US ) ) ) )
```

how would i extract just the first_name from both elements?

John and chris

Comment: my last attempt was trying:

`print_r( $cust[0]->first_name );`

to no avail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Array" you get back is a mishmash of Arrays and Objects, objects are accessed differently.

Array values are accessed by

```
$an_array = array('apple','banana');
$an_array[0]; //will return apple
```

While Object values area accessed by

```
$an_object->key;
```

Take a look at your return object

```
stdClass Object ( //<-- Object
  [orders] => Array ( //<-- Array
    [0] => stdClass Object (  //<-- Object
      [shipping_address] => stdClass Object ( //<-- Object
        [first_name] => John 
 etc..
```

So to get for example the first name you can access it with:

```
$arrayAndObjects->orders[0]->shipping_address->first_name
```

Hope that helps you understand it a bit, here are links to the php documentation for Arrays & Objects

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Thanks alot for the help Mario, the nesting was extremely confusing